# Series following a lone adventurer named Grey Wolf

Tags: story-identification

I’m hoping someone can help with this because it’s driving me crazy.  I read several books in a fantasy series back in the early ‘90’s, and I’ve been trying to track them down.  The series followed a lone adventurer named Grey Wolf (?), and I think they were tied into D&D somehow.  At least I remember getting them in the D&D section at the used bookstore.  I’m looking for the name of the  series and the author, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Greywolf is also the name of the bounty hunter in the Baldur's Gate video game, and is the name of a barbarian tribe of lycanthropes in the Forgotten Realms campaign setting (Which also had several related books/series).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it possible you're thinking of the [World of Greyhawk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gord_the_Rogue) setting? Gary Gygax wrote several novels in the late 80's set in his Greyhawk campaign setting

Answer (score 7):

[The Lone Wolf Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lone_Wolf_%28gamebooks%29) by Joe Deaver, illustrated by Gary Chalk.

You can also find (nearly) the whole series online now at [Project Aon.](http://www.projectaon.org/en/Main/Home) They've transferred most of the series, as well as the spin off books following the adventures of Grey Star the wizard and other series by the author such as his post-apocalyptic adventure Freeway Warrior, to HTML and made them freely available. Enjoy!

Answer (score 5):

You might be thinking of [The Witcher books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Witcher) by Andrzej Sapkowski. The first one was published in 1992 and the main character Geralt of Rivia is also called the White Wolf.

It has no tie-ins to D&D though.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be "The Grey King," part of the "The Dark is Rising" Series by Susan Cooper? I've been trying to place it for years because I was looking for "Grey Wolf" due to the wolf on the cover of one of the books in the series.

Comment: What makes you think this might be the correct answer? Just the wolf on the cover image?